# "Begin with F", "begin with an F" or "begin with F's"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have a question about singular and plural forms.

When you are solving a crossword puzzle with someone and trying to fill a row, which sentence can you say?

> Fail and flop both begin with **F**.
>
> Fail and flop both begin with **an F**.
>
> Fail and flop both begin with **F's**.

Comment: You can say any of them.

Comment: The third should read, "...both begin with Fs" (no apostrophe) since it's neither a possessive nor a contraction. Otherwise, they're all good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every sentence seems correct to me.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the most appropriate answer to say is, both begins with F's since they are not 1 word but I respect if anyone says another answer.

Comment: "both begins with"?